Delete cells to autofit columns to default size
I am using the below code to delete cells and autofit all columns in multiple sheets to default size. I am not a good writer of codes but used this to get results. My query, Is there a way to do this with better code.
Sub HM01_ClearData()

Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Cells.Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

Sheets("Sheet2").Select
Cells.Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

Sheets("Sheet3").Select
Cells.Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

Sheets("Sheet4").Select
Cells.Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

Sheets("Sheet5").Select
Cells.Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

Sheets("Sheet6").Select
Cells.Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

End Sub


Instead of 3 lines per sheet  get rid of the Select and try Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Delete Shift:=xlUp - but you're not autofitting any columns there

Adding a new sheet is a more efficient approach than clearing all cells on an existing sheet.
Sub HM01_ClearData()
    Const SHT_CNT = 6
    Dim i As Long, shtName As String
    For i = 1 To SHT_CNT
        shtName = "Sheet" & i
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Sheets(shtName).Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        Sheets.Add(after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = shtName
    Next
End Sub


If you try to clean all sheets in the workbook, pls try.
Sub ClearAllSht()
    Dim i As Long, shtName As String, sht As Worksheet
    For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        shtName = sht.Name
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        sht.Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        Sheets.Add(after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = shtName
    Next
End Sub


Perfect for what the OP needs, but will change the CodeName of each sheet.

@DarrenBartrup-Cook Yes, you are right. Thanks for the comment.
